# Day 8 of Sourdough Starter, is it still alive?

Tags: fermentation, sourdough, sourdough-starter

I started my starter 8 days ago. I stopped feeding it after Day 4. It has been left on the counter. It has been stirred but not fed for 4 days.

Is my starter still ok? It's kept in a mixing bowl with a towel over it and a rubberband.

Comment: Discard half, feed with equal parts flour and water, wait....

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-do-i-feed-a-sourdough-starter/1193#1193

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the temperature of your room, but you may still have enough left alive to save it. Is it still bubbling at all? You should throw most of it away and feed it and see if it changes and bubbles in the next few hours. I'd try keeping just a few tablespoons (maybe 100g of the starter, throwing the rest away) and add 500g of flour and 500g of 75°F water. If your flour is precious right now, you can use 250g and 250g instead.

You probably know this, but keep it in the fridge in the future if you're not going to be able to feed it for a while. Depending on the type of starter it can do well for a couple of weeks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! My starter does still have some bubbles and smells good. It's not going crazy or anything but seems to still be 'with us' lol.

Comment: That's good to hear. Look out for orange or pink in the starter, showing that it's bad and must be thrown away. Let me know if you're able to save it. Please mark this answer if that did it for you.

Comment: Sorry, it submitted before I could finish my response... my kitchen is usually between 65°-70°F. This time of year has been odd (in GA) but that's a range. Should I transfer my starter to a mason jar with a lid in the fridge (if I'm discarding)? My recipe I followed was to do 4oz flour (I used white all-purpose) and 4oz water.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean transfer to fridge if you're discarding? You should be able to keep your starter for up to six months in the fridge in an airtight container. Do not freeze it.